# Does the verb "unvelcro" exist or what can we use instead?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I know that the following word pairs exist:

> button – **un**button
>
> tie – **un**tie

Can we use an analogous process with the verb "velcro"?

Comment: You won't find it in a dictionary (other than [Urban Dictionary](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbandictionary.com%2Fdefine.php%3Fterm%3DUnvelcro&ei=60scVfvwIpOTNrezg5gB&usg=AFQjCNHNOPfmQ-tPiP-ELw--5js8CMlrRg&sig2=9JgOGsMRpN71375qeaSqJw&bvm=bv.89744112,d.eXY)) but I'm pretty sure that anyone who read it would know what you mean.

Comment: Velcro isn't a verb though. Something can be fastened or unfastened with velcro, but "velcroed" to me would mean attaching velcro to a object, not fastening something together with velcro.

Comment: @ColleenV I would say something like, "Let me velcro my sandals and we can go."

Comment: @Catija Are you sure you wouldn't be more likely to say "fasten my sandals" or "put on my sandals"? I can imagine folks using it as a verb, but I have never actually heard it even though I lived through the '80s ;). A quick survey at the coffee pot resulted in most folks thinking it was OK to use Velcro as a verb (AmE), but they weren't comfortable using unvelcro. It was a "one way" verb as they described it, sort of like "I stuck the note to the wall, then changed my mind and took it down." (not unstuck it).

Comment: @ColleenV I would use it in the same sense that I would use "Let me tie my shoes"... if they were on already but not fastened... and, yes, I would say "velcro".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

“Velcro” as a verb is already a [verbing](http://v.dreamwidth.org/263402/426) and a [genericization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark), which, however popular, doesn’t have quite the currency or flexibility of words in use for centuries. As [Catija](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/16318/catija) says, “unvelcro” can easily be understood, but it’s more comfortable for me to keep “velcro” as a noun and say things like this:

> I **undid** the velcro on my sneakers before kicking them across the room.
>
> He **ripped open** the velcro on his wallet and everyone in the library looked at him.

Comment: What about "unstrapped"?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers and comments!!!

Comment: @Ann You’re welcome! Just so you know, this site has a built-in mechanism for gratitude whereby you can thank people by upvoting (clicking triangle above number next to question) and/or accepting (clicking check mark).

Comment: OK, I'll keep that in mind!